# Creating a stop button in order to stop the recording in c# windows form application

Tags: c#, windows, record

I have a windows form application which contains two buttons, record and stop record. When the record button is pressed, an object of a class capture is created and a function which captures a kinect stream is called which continuously stores the stream:

```
while (scanner.TryNext() && flag == false)
{ 
    // the stream store as long as flag is false
}
```

I want to create a second button in which the flag is going to take value true in order to stop recording. However I have noticed that if I change the value of the class in a different object, the flag does not change value in the method that was called in the first object and the recording still happens. Therefore I am wondering how it is possible for the two objects to communicate in order to stop the recording of the stream.

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Capturer obj = new Capturer(dirPath + "Crathan", 20); // the record begins
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Capturer capt = new Capturer();
    capt.flag = true;
}
```

Different constructor which changes the default value of flag which is false to true. However this approach doesnt work.

Comment: Don't do `flag == false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an entirely new object each time, which is local / exists only within the scope of the click handler function.

The `obj` in `button5_Click` is totally different from the `capt` in `button3_click`.

What you need to do is to hold a reference to the object somewhere (almsot certainly as a private field of the containing class) where both methods can access the *same* object.

For example:

```
private Capturer _capturer;

private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     _capturer= new Capturer(dirPath + "Crathan", 20); // the record begins
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _capturer.flag = true;
}
```

For better design, don't create the Capturer when the click happens (or else someone might click the stop button before _capturer was initialised).

Better would be to construct it in the class constructor with the relevant parameters then have a method to begin the capture, and one to stop it.

```
void MyClass()
{
    _capturer = new Capturer(dirPath + "Crathan", 20);
}

private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     _capture.Start();
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _capturer.Stop();
}
```

Comment: Make sense. However what is happerning in the case I press firstly the button3 instead of button5?

Comment: I was editing to add a not about that as you commented.

Comment: The prob is that i have to create the object inside the button5.

Comment: Cool I will change slightly my approach I will disable the buttons in order to be able to be pressed in specific order.